# Wrong result of sympy integration with symbol limits

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-integration

```
from sympy import *
s = Symbol("s")
y = Symbol("y")
raw_function = 1/(150.0-0.5*y)
result = integrate(raw_function, (y, 0, s)
```

The above snippet gets a wrong result: `-2.0*log(0.5*s - 150.0) + 10.0212705881925 + 2.0*I*pi`,
but we can know the right result is `-2.0*log(-0.5*s + 150.0) + 10.0212705881925`, so what's wrong?

Comment: The two expressions are equivalent for `s < 300` but differ by `4*pi` for `s > 300`. The integral itself is undefined for `s > 300` though.

Comment: Are you sure the two expressions are the same? I don't have a pen and paper at hand but the the sign in front of the s (hence the derivative) don't seem tto agree. First one is a decreasing function with s, the second one is increasing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the correct result, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%28150.0-0.5*y%29%2C%7By%2C0%2Cs%7D%5D) says it is the same as Sympy here.

Edit:

This function diverges (and the integral too) around y=300, see its plot here (it diverges the same way as 1/x does but offset to y=300)

[image]

Meaning that you are constrained to `s < 300` to have a well defined (and finite) integrale. In that range, the value of the integral is equal to what sympy is providing you.